# I have created three textboxes in C# and I want to do a difference math calculation

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my code:

```
private void txtDeposit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value1, value2, result = 0;
        value1 = double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
        value2 = double.Parse(txtDeposit.Text);
        result = value1 - value2;
        txtBalance.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

And here is my input block to the database:

```
cn.Open();
cm = new SqlCommand("insert into tblLayby (brid, cname, phone, email, pdesc, price, deposit, balance, date) values(@brid, @cname, @phone, @email, @pdesc, @price, @deposit, @balance, @date)", cn);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brid", brid); 
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", cboClient.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdesc", cboProduct.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", double.Parse(txtPrice.Text));
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deposit", double.Parse(txtDeposit.Text));
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", double.Parse(txtBalance.Text));
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.Value);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Layby has been successfully saved!", title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
Clear();
```

Now I am getting this error: "Input string was not in a correct format." How can I resolve this? The data is uploaded in the table, but the error still shows.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Do not use AddWithValue: [1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: On value1 = double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);

Comment: The AddWithValue works fine. But on the value1 line is where I am getting that error. I don't know what I am missing

Comment: have you actually looked at the values of the textboxes

Comment: I have got the solution. The problem was that I was using double instead of decimal. These values are monetary. Thanks for your help